# DOS for arbitrary volume

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

One can easily derive for the Density of States (DOS) of photons $D(\omega)=\frac{V\omega^2}{\pi^2c^3}$ by assuming that the volume is a cube. Is it possible to apply this formula also for different volumes (at least approximately) since we can build every volume from small cubes?

Comment: In general, the shape of the volume will determine the discrete energy spacing. The continuum limit is obtained in the infinite volume limit where the original shape does not matter and you always get your formula for $D(\omega)$. Intuitively, this is because it is a property of free space, i.e. $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @lpz so does that mean for a finite volume I cannot use this formula?

Comment: It wouldn’t be exact, but accurate enough if the edge effects are negligible.